# Can ogr2ogr be used to append multiple DBF files?

Tags: ogr2ogr

Can ogr2ogr be used to append multiple DBF files? It works with SHP files, but I can't see how to do it with DBF files on their own. It ought to be possible, considering DBF is a subset of SHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have three DBF files with the same field structure (schema), and you want to combine them into one `all.dbf`. From a system shell, use ogr2ogr with the `-append` flag:

```
$ ogr2ogr -append all.dbf a.dbf
$ ogr2ogr -append all.dbf b.dbf
$ ogr2ogr -append all.dbf c.dbf
```

These files can be either shapefiles or sole DBF files. It will work either way.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have dozens of files and all your shapefiles are in a single folder you can use the Vector->Data management Tools->Merge shapefiles to one tool in QGIS.  Either, that or write a simple Python script to iterate Mike's solution above over the contents of a folder.